# Any memory efficient mapping function from a square 2d space to 1d space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, graphing-functions, special-functions

I do programming questions but many a times I come across some problem in which I think I should make an effort to reduce both time and space complexity.
For example, I want to convert given coordinates (0,0 to n,n). Consider a square matrix. Now I want my program to mark the coordinates that I have already visited. For that I have to save the x,y coordinates in a pair<int,int> object. I was wondering if I could save them in a single primitive type variable.
E.g. x,y ---(Function 1)----> z   and  z--(Function 2)--> x,y

Is this possible?
Here we should get a unique value of z for every different pair of x,y and for each value of z we should get unique coordinates x,y.
I want to implement these 2 functions, that do the forward and backward mapping.

Comment: There are lots of ways of representing pairs of numbers as single numbers. 
See the [Wikipedia page on pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) for an example. I don't think any of them are very attractive for your purposes as the decoding is typically computational expensive.

Comment: Another unattractively impractical (but theoretically important) method is [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel_numbering): $(x,y) \mapsto z = 2^x 3^y$. The decoding comes from factorization algorithms. The domain of the decoding is all natural numbers $z$ having only $2$ and $3$ for prime factors. The formula for the decoding is: compute $x$ to be the exponent of $2$ in prime factorization of $z$; and compute $y$ to be the exponent of $3$.

Comment: This way it will take a lot of memory space if we'll increase the value of x and y. Not a memory-efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with integers then $$z=x+(n+1)y$$ would work in one direction while rounding down with the floor function (or integer division) $$y = \lfloor z/(n+1)\rfloor \text{ and } x=z-(n+1)\lfloor z/(n+1)\rfloor$$ would work in the other.  Since $0 \le x \le n$ and $0 \le y \le n$ you have $0 \le z \le n^2+2n$, and this is in effect a bijection.